# How to read output from linux process status (ps) command in R?

Tags: r, memory, io, system, text-formatting

here is the data.txt:

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND  
root         1  0.0  0.0   2280   728 ?        Ss   20:44   0:00 init [2]    
root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    20:44   0:00 [kthreadd]  
root       202  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   20:44   0:00 [ext4-dio-unwri  
root       334  0.0  0.1   2916  1452 ?        Ss   20:44   0:00 udevd --daemon
```

how to read the data into a data.frame?
1.can not to decide separator
the last field is a problem,`space` can not be the separator,
init [2]   ,udevd --daemon  are the one field,can not be separated by `space`.
2.no fixed width
every line has different width.

so ,how can i read the data.txt into a  data.frame?

Comment: Are you sure that there are no fixed widths here? This seems to be fixed width except for the last column.

Comment: I'm able to read this sample you've provided with `read.fwf("data.txt", widths = c(4, 10, 5, 5, 7, 6, 4, 10, 6, 7, 20), skip = 1)`. Can't get the headers to work, that's why I have `skip = 1`, but those are easy to add in. The last width can be just set much larger than you expect and you should be fine... I think....

Comment: @AnandaMahto - I think using `read.fwf` will be problematic as the `ps` linux command which is used to generate this text will use different sized columns each time it is run dependent on the values needed to be printed. I have commented below that the output format can however be manually specified when using the program.

Comment: @thelatemail, or Thela, or whatever it may be ;), I didn't catch that part, but now that you've edited the title, I see the problem....

Answer (score 4):

I would do it like this:

```
library(stringr) # has a convenient function for splitting to a fixed length 

raw          <- system("ps aux", intern = TRUE)
fields       <- strsplit(raw[1], " +")[[1]]
ps           <- str_split_fixed(raw[-1], " +", n = length(fields))
colnames(ps) <- fields
```

Comment: Awesome, avoids any external file-I/O! `raw` is an R builtin, best to not shadow it, call the variable `out` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a one-liner that should do the trick:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(strsplit(readLines("data.txt"), "\\s+"), function(fields) c(fields[1:10], paste(fields[-(1:10)], collapse = " "))))
```

This is what it does in detail:

1. read all lines of the file via `readLines` (results in a character vector where each vector element is one line of the file)
2. use `strsplit` to split each line into strigs separated by white space (`\\s+`)
3. for each line (`lapply`), merge all fields that come after the 10th field into one (via `paste(..., collapse = " ")`)---this creates a list where each list element represents one line of the file and is a character vector of length 11 (one for each field)
4. finally, call `rbind` to merge the list into a matrix (or data frame)

Answer (score 0):

What format is your data in?  If you can open it in Excel saving it as a tab delminated file is most likely the best way to move forward.

Saving files as a tab deliminated file is one of the more common ways to prepare data for import into `R`.  This can be done in Excel by 'saving as' '.txt (tab deliminated)'.  once this is done:

```
my_data <- read.table("path/to/file/", header = TRUE, sep = "\t")
```

`sep = "\t"` tells R that your file is tab deliminated

Comment: please use command in linux `ps aux`,you can get the format file,`\t`can not be used here.

Comment: @KillKill - it might be worth looking at this question for how to redirect `ps aux` to a csv: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114741/generating-a-csv-list-from-linux-ps Looking at `man ps` you can specify output formats.