# How to get OOB error of each tree in a random forest, by package 'randomForest'

Tags: r, random-forest

Is there any method to get OOB error for each trees in the forest? The package provides access to 'importanceSD', but I didn't find how to get OOB error for each tree.

Answer (score 0):

OOB errors for each tree are printed in the output when you train the rf.

(If it's not available afterwards as an attribute on the rf object, you need to programmatically capture the output with `capture.output` or temporarily redirect stdout to file, then do a little text-processing... see e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14432052/how-to-read-output-from-linux-process-status-ps-command-in-r))